# What is a good layout for advanced database filtering?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have a RecyclerView, showing values from a database. When the page is first loaded, it shows all results, however I want the user to be able to filter by certain string inputs, true/false values, etc. My current layout has a DrawerLayout, with one of the views being a fragment containing the said RecyclerView.

Since I already have a fragment, what would be a clean way to show the options for searching? There will likely be 5-6 different options, so just always showing them at the top won't work. Also, a simple search bar won't work, because there are more options than just 1 string input.

Comment: I like the way that Property Apps (In Australia the Domain app) do their filtering; i.e., Hold it in a Navigation Drawer where you can do more than just a single Text Filter.

Comment: The question is quite subjective, but that's how I'd do this: I would create Coordinator Layout with AppBarLayout, where I'd put these options (why AppBarLayout? because it has option to be shown on scroll up without need to scroll to the very top of the list). Therefore, you can place your RecyclerView fragment in the same CoordinatorLayout as body. 
Antoher option is to create OptionsMenu in the Toolbar, or show Dialog on some button (FAB?) click

Answer (score 0):

For my recent projects I implemented this kind of UI for data filtering and clients enjoyed it a lot. So, I would encourage you to try something like this . **Just a right nav drawer which sits under toolbar to maintain hierarchy**. *As **top level is reserved** for main nav- drawer on **left**.*

[image]

[image]

Do let me know if this inspires you.

Comment: Looks very elegant, however since I do sometimes need typed input from the user, not sure how well it would work.

Comment: @StaticShadow You could have input field with edit icon when user clicks you could try opening a material dialog for input and update the value in nav drawer field. I think that will work fine if you chose to go with this way.